# Transform not found in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf, joblib

I am using TfidfVectorizer for vectorize my data. Firstly I initiates it, then I fit it, dump and when I try to load and do transform function I get this error:

```
transform not found
```

and my code looks like this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=500, lowercase=True, analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 5))

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['content'])
joblib.dump(X, "./vectorizer.pkl")

vectorizer = joblib.load("./vectorizer.pkl")
# vectorizer here is scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix type
X = vectorizer.transform(df['content'])
```

What is wrong here?

**FIXED**

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=500, lowercase=True, analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 5))

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['content'])
joblib.dump(vectorizer, "./vectorizer.pkl")

vectorizer = joblib.load("./vectorizer.pkl")
X = vectorizer.transform(df['content'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `vectorizer = joblib.load("./vectorizer.pkl")`. You are overwriting the vectorizer therefore it no longer has transform method.

Comment: Thank You, I already fixed it. I shoulded dump ```vectorizer```, not ```X``` and now it works.